# Choosing the name of an app

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I've just started with Android Studio and I'm finding it hard to see the name of the apk file I want to put in the Google Play so that lots of people can buy it.

Ler's say I want the name of the app to be "Happy Days" where in the many parts of Android Studio should I put this phrase? I would like the apk to be HappyDays.apk. The package is com.companyname.happydays

Comment: "I would like the apk to be HappyDays.apk" -- why are you worrying about this? If you are putting the app on the Play Store, the user never sees the APK file name. For the "Happy Days" that the user will see, a stock Android Studio project will have that be in the `app_name` string resource, which in turn is used by your `<application>` element in your manifest.

Comment: plus 1 the user will never see it

Comment: To add to what @CommonsWare said, if you are putting the app on the Play Store, you can change the title of the Play Store listing inside the Play Store console and it doesn't have to match the name from `<application>`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your package has a different name, or your main class is not called HappyDays, you can set the name and change it any time in the Google Play console. You do however need to put the name on the app_name folder as @CommonWare indicates. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your wisdom. When I generate a signed APK in Android studio the file that is made is app-release.apk. Can I just rename this to HappyDays.apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do a few things:

```
1)change your project name to HappyDays so that the generated apk file would read HappyDays.apk, this doesn't matters much by the way.

2)Add this under the application tag in your manifest file:

      android:label="Happy Days"    // This is the main thing which displays up as your app name, which everyone sees.
```